# Libgdx and Dagger 2 - not generating code

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, libgdx, dagger-2

I am working on porting my libgdx game to support dependency injection through Graddle 2.

The problem I am encountering is that dagger does not seem to be be generating code for my components. I believe the problem lies in the way libgdx deal with it's gradle files and how it splits them up for different operating systems.

The entirety of my (very incomplete) project can be found [here](https://github.com/lucascauthen/Aquifree) but I am going to post the code for the project targeted for only android.

My build.gradle for the whole project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'Aquifree'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.5'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
        //provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
        provided 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
        provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

My build.gradle for the android module:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileSdkVersion 22
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.lucascauthen.aquifree.android/com.lucascauthen.aquifree.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle for the core module:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

My module class AssetLoaderModule.java:

```
package com.lucascauthen.modules;
import com.lucascauthen.util.AssetLoader;


import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;


@Module
public class AssetLoaderModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    AssetLoader provideAssetLoader() {
        return new AssetLoader();
    }
}
```

My component AssetLoaderComponent.java

```
package com.lucascauthen.components;

import com.lucascauthen.util.AssetLoader;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AssetLoader.class})
public interface AssetLoaderComponent {
    AssetLoader provideAssetLoader();
}
```

Finally, and instance where I try to create an AssetLoader object:

```
package com.lucascauthen.screens.MenuItems;

import com.lucascauthen.components.AssetLoaderComponent;
import com.lucascauthen.components.*;

import com.lucascauthen.util.AssetLoader;

public abstract class MenuItem {
    protected AssetLoader assetLoader;
    public abstract void dispose();
    public MenuItem() {
        AssetLoaderComponent component = DaggerAssetLoaderComponent.create();
        assetLoader = component.provideAssetLoader();
    }
}
```

The problem occurs on the line with `DaggerAssetLoaderComponent.create()`The compiler does not recognize the symbol and thus the code is being generated.

What I have tried:

- Cleaning/building/assembling the project
- Adding the dependencies/plugins to the android module itself
- Checking the projects files to see if the code is there but just hiding (Its not there)
- I setup dagger in a non-libgdx project and got it to work just fine
- I have tried using both glassfish annotations and the jrs250 annotations
- I tried limiting the project to only android by using the setup file to generate a project for only android. (The github link contains the code for more than just the android operating system however)

At this point I am thinking it just something silly regarding how I am adding the different files to the various build.gradle files. If you need more information, please comment below.

Comment: From the entire day I worked on trying to get this to work, it seems like libgdx and dagger 2 are incompatible. I do not know why, however.

Comment: I am working on this as well. I see the class generated, and get the Dagger class. At first, IntelliJ IDEA did not 'see' the code, that was because by default the .java file is generated in build/intermediates/classes, instead of build/generated/source/apt. Do you find DaggerAssetLoaderComponent.java somewhere in build directory?

Comment: When I tried it, I couldn't find the generated files as if they were never created.

Comment: Actually I have integrated Dagger 2 in our libgdx project now. Works fine for desktop and android (not yet tried for RoboVM / iOS, we will start on that soon)

Comment: Is there any way you could post you gradle files? That might help me see what I am doing wrong. Or at least the part that pertains to dagger 2?

Answer (score 2):

It works well in our project, but we have a highly customized gradle build in our libgdx project.

Relevant build.gradle snippets below.

project root build.gradle:

```
     buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

            // Android apt (without this, .java files are generated in classes dir instead of generated sources dir)
            // resulting in errors IDE
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

            // Desktop apt (without this, .java files are generated in classes dir instead of generated sources dir)
            // resulting in errors IDE
            classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.3"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        }
    }
```

In android module, neenbedankt android-apt plugin needs to be applied:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

In desktop module, ltgt apt plugin needs to be applied. Additionally, idea plugin needs to be applied, otherwise build/generated/source/apt/main is not recognized as source folder by IDEA.

```
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: 'idea' // plugin needed to make IDEA see build/generated/source/apt/main as sourcefolder.
```

Comment: I will check to see if this works for me very soon. Thanks so much!